# How do I create a Horizontal Scroll View with ViewPager functionality?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, horizontalscrollview

I've tried figuring out a way to solve this problem by using the viewpager but I've been unable to do so entirely.

Here is the tasks I have been assigned to solve:

[image]

- Create a view that allows for pagination*(Solved by using a View Pager and swapping between two fragments)
- Have the two views share the same background with a parallaxing effect( Example: Elements in the red view on below move slightly slower than the background when pagin to the green view)
- Find a way for these two views to "share" graphics. The idea is to have an animation on the red view that "crosses over" to the green view.

Is there any way of solving this on the Android platform? Is there a way to simply define one layout that is larger than the phones dimension and somehow be able to page between the visible part of the view and the non-visible part?

Answer (score 1):

you should work on  onInterceptTouchEvent. when you click on the horizontalScrollview you should return false in  onInterceptTouchEvent else return true;

Here is, How i did

1)make CustomViewpager extending ViewPager
2)override onInterceptTouchEvent like this

```
 @Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
     if (childId > 0) {
         View scroll = findViewById(childId);
         if (scroll != null) {
             Rect rect = new Rect();
             scroll.getHitRect(rect);
             if (rect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
                 return false;
             }
         }
     }
     return true;
}
private int childId;
public void setChildId(int id) {
    this.childId = id;
}
```

3)use customViewpager instead of viewpager in xml like this

```
<com.packagename.CustomViewpager .....
```

4) and set childId from activity like this

```
CustomViewpager cv=(CustomViewpager)findViewById(R.id.id_of_customviewpager);
cv.setChildId(R.id.id_of_customviewpager);
```

5)done

Logic is when you touch HorizontalScrollview give the touch to child other wise give touch to parent

Comment: This sort of works.  If you scroll vertically, the hit rect of the child doesn't change.  Paging gestures on the original position of the displaced child are not intercepted.

Comment: @chrish,Stopped viewpager swipe,In my case ViewPager page is contains ScrollView inside that i have 2 HorizontalScrollView, Now below this HorizontalScrollView viewpager swipe not working. Any possible solution?